# Spring boot - A single @Configuration @import will work but multiple will not, why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

In a Spring boot project, I have a RestController that contains:

```
@Autowired
private ProactiveDbManager proactiveDbManager;

@Autowired
private CoreDbManager coreDbManager;
```

Theses 2 db managers are in another Spring boot module, so I'm importing them with a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Import({ProactiveDbCommonsConfig.class})
public class ProactiveDbConfig {

}
```

and:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Import({CoreDbCommonsConfig.class})
public class CoreDbConfig {

}
```

`ProactiveDbCommonsConfig` and `CoreDbCommonsConfig` are also configurations.
`ProactiveDbCommonsConfig`:

```
@Configuration
public class ProactiveDbCommonsConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProactiveDbCommonsConfig.class);

    private ProactiveDbManager proactiveDbManager;
    @Bean
    public MasterHandler masterHandler() {
        return new MasterHandler(true);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProactiveDbManager dBManager(MasterHandler masterHandler) {
        List<String> dbConnectionStrings = masterHandler.getDbConnectionStringsJsonsList(DbConsts.DEFAULT_DATA_CENTER);
        LOGGER.debug("DB manager created.");
        proactiveDbManager = new ProactiveDbManager(dbConnectionStrings);
        return proactiveDbManager;
    }


    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        try {
            closeDbConnection();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void closeDbConnection() throws Exception {
        if (this.proactiveDbManager != null) {
            this.proactiveDbManager.disconnect();
            this.proactiveDbManager = null;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I remove 1 of the autowired in the controller and remove its configuration (i.e `ProactiveDbConfig`) then it works. Both of them work alone, but not together.

The error I get is:

```
Field coreDbManager in x.y.z.controllers.h required a bean of type 'x.y.a.db.managers.CoreDbManager' that could not be found.
```

Stack trace:

```
15:56:14.609 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'x.y.db.managers.CoreDbManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at x.y.app.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:66)
15:56:14.609 [main] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
```

Comment: show us CoreDbCommonsConfig and ProactiveDbCommonsConfig

Comment: As you are using Spring Boot don't use the `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`  Spring Boot already loads that for you.

Comment: Please add error log of the scenario when all configurations and @Autowired beans are in place (as you intended originally)

Comment: @ScanQR Edited, you can see it now.

Comment: You need to use qualifier. So this way spring will understand which manager it needs to use.

Comment: You only added the `ProactiveDbCommonsConfig` please add the `CoreDbCommonsConfig` as well. And please add the full stacktrace instead of only a snippet of the message.

Comment: @M.Deinum stack trace was added, CoreDbCommonsConfig is exactly the same, with respective name.

Comment: If they are exactly the same then that is your issue. One bean either overrides the other (depending on your Spring Boot version) or you end up with multiple.

Comment: @M.Deinum The structure is the same but each of them is a manager of another database (uses different classes)

Comment: @SahinYanlık doesn't help

Comment: As mentioned multiple times, then please add them. Also this isn't the complete stacktrace, just more of the logging including a message.

Comment: The fact that it are different classes doesn't matter if the bean -name (by default the name of the method!) is the same. Then one overrides the other.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! changing the name of the methods inside helped! You can add it as an answer, so I will accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `@Configuration` classes and not explicitly defining a name of the bean in `@Bean(name = "<your-name-here>")` the methodname will be used as the name of the bean.

If you import multiple configuration files which contain beans with the same name one will override the other. Newer versions of Spring Boot prevent this by disable overriding (which is enabled by default) which will lead to an exception upon startup.

In your case the solution, either rename the method or add an explicit name to the `@Bean` annotation.